# Powershell arrays, functions and reference

Tags: powershell

I understand Powershell arrays are immutable objects and like all objects, are passed by reference to functions. But what I don't understand in the below example is why `$b` doesn't have the same values as `$a`.

The only difference is that `$b` is not strongly typed. Does that mean that `Test-ByRefArray` casts `$b` from `[object[]]` to `[string[]]`, a new object is actually created, which would explain why changes made by `Test-ByRefArray` on this new object have no impact on the original object ?

```
function Test-ByRefArray {
    param (
        [string[]] $Array1,
        [string[]] $Array2
    )
    $Array1[0] = "Modified by Test-ByRefArray"
    $Array2[0] = "Modified by Test-ByRefArray"
}

function Test-Array {
    [string[]] $a = 'hello', 'world'
    $b = 'hello', 'world'
    $c = $a #by ref: if a is updated, so is $c

    Test-ByRefArray -Array1 $a -Array2 $b

    $a -join ", "
    $b -join ", "
    $c -join ", "
}

Test-Array
```

Output:

```
Modified by Test-ByRefArray, world
hello, world
Modified by Test-ByRefArray, world
```

Comment: I'm not sure "immutable" is the right adjective here, after all you do _mutate_ the contents of the array :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right, the content of the array is mutable, but the structure of the array is immutable (can't add or delete elements without creating an entirely new array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens here is that the type of `$a` satisfies the type constraint of `$Array1` - it's *already* a `[string[]]`, and PowerShell passes it to your function as-is - so `$Array1` now holds a reference to the *exact same* array as `$a` has a reference to at the call site.

`$b`, on the other hand, is implicitly typed `[object[]]` - and `[object[]]` does **not** satisfy the type constraint `[string[]]` on `$Array2`:

```
PS ~> [string[]].IsAssignableFrom([object[]])
False
```

Since PowerShell wants to be helpful, it *converts* the array to a new `[string[]]`, and so `$Array2` refers to this new array that has been created during parameter binding.

For this reason, the contents of the array referenced by `$b` is never modified - `$Array2` references a completely different array.

---

We can observe whether type conversion (or type *coercion*) occurs in the output from [`Trace-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command), here in Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```
PS ~> Trace-Command -Expression {&{param([string[]]$ParamArray)} @([string[]]@())} -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND arg [System.String[]] to parameter [ParamArray]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         result returned from DATA GENERATION: System.String[]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [ParamArray] SUCCESSFUL
```

The output might look a bit confusing at first, but here we can see PowerShell using the type constraint of the `$ParamArray` parameter and determines that the input argument is already of type `[string[]]` - no actual work needed.

Now let's pass an implicitly typed array instead:

```
PS ~> Trace-Command -Expression {&{param([string[]]$ParamArray)} @(@())} -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND arg [System.Object[]] to parameter [ParamArray]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         result returned from DATA GENERATION: System.Object[]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Binding collection parameter ParamArray: argument type [Object[]], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], no coerceElementType
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Arg is IList with 0 elements
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Creating array with element type [System.String] and 0 elements
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Argument type System.Object[] is IList
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [ParamArray] SUCCESSFUL
```

Here, on the other hand, we see PowerShell creating a new array (third to last debug statement) and then binding *that* to `$ParamArray`.

Comment: Awesome answer! So type constraints on functions can have big performance implications when done without caring which is something I don't normally see explained.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, I had a feeling it was due to typecasting!